# How to resolve cairos dependencies on Suse using zypper

Tags: opensuse

I am trying to install intel-gpu-tools on Open Suse. And it fails with the following error message while its trying to resolve Cairos dependencies. Error message pasted below.

I could get away with this on ubuntu using apt-get build-dep gtk+2.0.

Is there something similar for zypper as well that would resolve all the build dependencies.

checking for cairo's PNG functions feature... 
configure: WARNING: Could not find libpng in the pkg-config search path
checking whether cairo's PNG functions feature could be enabled... no
configure: error: recommended PNG functions feature could not be enabled

Answer (score 0):

sudo zypper install libgtk

This installs all the dependencies requires for cairo.